# Another Public Static IP Address?

Tags: ip-address, static-ip

We currently have two servers, one of which has a static IP address allowing remote access from outside.

We now need the other server to be accessible from outside, I'm presuming we need to obtain another static IP address?  Is it simple to assign this to the server?

Comment: Depends on if you have a router. If so, too don't need another ip address, and you can just port forward

Comment: @Luke - although +1 for the suggestion, it really is very router dependent. We had offices all over but the routers were bog standard with no NAT, and the only way port forwarding worked was by changing each PC in the building form 3389 to xxxx! Long  :)

Comment: @DaveRook For servers with remote desktop, that's what I would do. Otherwise, setup a VPN then I can just type the DNS name for each server. But because it was an incomplete answer and sent from my phone, I made it a comment instead

Comment: @Luke that depends on if they need to access the same port, as the same port. Such as accessing port 80 on both boxes, while requiring the access to both ports to be port 80. At that point a second IP would be necessary.

Comment: @Dave - that's what a Terminal Server Gateway is for...

Comment: @scape Only if the PUBLIC port needs to be the same... For example, HTTP, POP, SMTP, RDP, VNC, etc can all enter from the client a port number to connect to

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you included more detail in response to an answer above regarding your CRM.

The safer alternative is to add a Remote Desktop gateway to your web server environment.  This server then acts as a gateway to terminate RDP sessions to whatever computers you have setup.  There are lots of other details about that but the gist is simple: setup a gateway, avoid the whole VPN craziness and let clients use the built in terminal service session over a secure 443 session.

Comment: This. I literally wrote it in a comment at the same time you posted this answer. The only catch with TS Gateways are old versions of Windows XP that don't do NLA (and none of them have it enabled by default), and that you can't log on if you have an expired password.

Comment: @MarkHenderson All good and valid points.  I just make sure to have XP fully patched and in some cases simply use the less secure RDP protocol to avoid XP problems, either way, it provides a much easier to implement and maintain solution for most cases. Oh and its a RD Gateway now ;)

Comment: So it is, I still find myself using the old terminology, even though it's been what, 4 years now?

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yessir! It's all good though!

Comment: The problem is the CRM needs to be 'accessible' by the public i.e. people that are not users on our network for event registrations etc.

Comment: So does your CRM expose a web interface or something else? Sounds like thats just a matter of opening port 80/HTTP to allow them to access the specific functionality you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is that simple - although you probably have to do this either via your ISP or your hosting provider.

If doing this by yourself then the chances are the ISP will update to a fixed IP, but your line etc will remain the same and no installation / work is required. So you just wait until the line is set up and ensure it is directed to your server / router / set up.

Depending on what you're after, there are also paid for remote desktop services such as TeamViewer and LogMeIn (although doubtful they will be useful if you need them for a server).

Comment: Thanks for your help, as I thoguht then.

Basically we need to reach the new server as that is where our CRM is.  We want to allow remote/customer access to that.